# format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[64]

Tags: c

I'm creating a program using `C`, and I have this line in my code :

```
scanf("%s", &path);
```

When I compile the source file, I get this warning :

```
main.c:84:2: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[64]’ [-Wformat]
```

And this is the declaration for the `path` variable :

```
char path[64];
```

Why I'm seeing this error? And how can I solve it ?

Comment: Are you using Unicode strings? If so, `scanf()` doesn't.

Comment: @JonathanWood, What do you mean by Unicode strings ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An array is already a pointer-like object (as dreamlax points out). You don't need the `&` operator, since declaring

```
char path[64];
```

is equivalent to setting `path` to a pointer to a 64-byte region of memory.

Comment: Arrays and pointers are not the same thing. Arrays can decay to pointers but they have different semantics. `sizeof` for example, will give you the size of the array, not the size of a pointer. An array is also an unmodifiable lvalue (e.g. you can't assign a new array to it).

Answer (score 5):

The `%s` format specifier requires you to supply a `char *`, which is a pointer to `char`.  You are passing `&path`, which is a pointer to an array.  You can just pass `path` by itself, which will evaluate to a pointer to the first element of the array (the same as `&path[0]`).

Answer (score 1):

try this `scanf("%s", path);` instead because I think `path` is an array and a pointer to an array is the array name itself ( array == &array  )